# icacls: overwrite existing ACL with a DENY ACE

Tags: access-control-list, ntfs

Icacls with /grant:r will replace any previously granted explicit permissions with new ones specified. But there is no :r switch for /deny. So if one wants to completely replace an existing ACL with an explicit DENY, he should first remove single occurrences of existing SIDs and then apply an explicit DENY.

Is there a way of directly overwriting an existing ACL with a DENY ACL entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably by design because denies override grants.  However, you can deny and remove as separate steps

```
icacls yourdirectory /deny user:r (or whatever) 
icacls yourdirectory /remove:g user
```